# Joining by field and changing it at the same time

Tags: sql

I have two tables - one with people who have emails and other with email list. Some of emails need to be cleared.

I'm thinking of the query like this:

```
UPDATE Person
SET Person.Email=''
FROM Person INNER Join EmailList
ON Person.Email=EmailList.Email
And EmailList.Reset='Y'
```

My question is - will it work? Will it make a joined new table first and then change the values or may joining and value changing somehow interfere and make unpredictable result?

Comment: My answer is - did you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work fine...unless you have some errors in the names in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Person
INNER Join EmailList
ON Person.Email=EmailList.Email
And EmailList.Reset='Y'
SET Person.Email=''
```